# Pandas and DateTime TypeError: cannot compare a TimedeltaIndex with type float

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I have a pandas DataFrame Series time differences that looks like::

```
 print(delta_t)

 1       0 days 00:00:59
 3       0 days 00:04:22
 6       0 days 00:00:56
 8       0 days 00:01:21
 19      0 days 00:01:09
 22      0 days 00:00:36
 ...
```

(the full DataFrame had a bunch of NaNs which I dropped).

I'd like to know which delta_t's are less than 1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute, 
so I tried:

```
delta_t_lt1day = delta_t[np.where(delta_t < 30.)]
```

but then got a:

```
TypeError: cannot compare a TimedeltaIndex with type float
```

Little help?!?!

Comment: shouldn't it be `np.where(delta_t < timedelta(days=1))`. you can't compare across type unless implicitly castable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your Series is in `timedelta` format, you can skip the `np.where`, and index using something like this, where you compare your actual values to other timedeltas, using the appropriate units:

```
delta_t_lt1day = delta_t[delta_t < pd.Timedelta(1,'D')]

delta_t_lt1hour = delta_t[delta_t < pd.Timedelta(1,'h')]

delta_t_lt1minute = delta_t[delta_t < pd.Timedelta(1,'m')]
```

You'll get the following series:

```
>>> delta_t_lt1day
0
1    00:00:59
3    00:04:22
6    00:00:56
8    00:01:21
19   00:01:09
22   00:00:36
Name: 1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
>>> delta_t_lt1hour
0
1    00:00:59
3    00:04:22
6    00:00:56
8    00:01:21
19   00:01:09
22   00:00:36
Name: 1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
>>> delta_t_lt1minute
0
1    00:00:59
6    00:00:56
22   00:00:36
Name: 1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [TimeDelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html) class:

```
import pandas as pd

deltas = pd.to_timedelta(['0 days 00:00:59',
                          '0 days 00:04:22',
                          '0 days 00:00:56',
                          '0 days 00:01:21',
                          '0 days 00:01:09',
                          '0 days 00:31:09',
                          '0 days 00:00:36'])

for e in deltas[deltas < pd.Timedelta(value=30, unit='m')]:
    print(e)
```

**Output**

```
0 days 00:00:59
0 days 00:04:22
0 days 00:00:56
0 days 00:01:21
0 days 00:01:09
0 days 00:00:36
```

Note that this filter outs `'0 days 00:31:09'` as expected. The expression `pd.Timedelta(value=30, unit='m')` creates a time delta of 30 minutes.